# How to connect a WhatsApp group to Telegram group? any bot is there?

Tags: telegram, whatsapp, telegram-bot

If we can connect a WhatsApp group to telegram group and get messages from whatsapp to telegram and vice versa then that will be great. Is any bot program available to do that. How to setup a bridge or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. There is a repository called wat-bridge using which you can connect WhatsApp and Telegram. wat-bridge will act as a member in a whatsapp group and read all messages and then pass it to Telegram bot. Detailed instructions about setting up wat-bridge bot is available in [this blog](https://ibcomputing.com/whatsapp-telegram-bridge/)

wat-bridge is released under MIT License and the source code is available in [github](https://github.com/rmed/wat-bridge)

There is also a Video Tutorial about setting up this bot which is available in [Youtube](https://youtu.be/lVsFW6Jt8CU)

NB: This number may get banned by whatsapp by using yowsup, so use at your own risk! Also, don’t use your primary WhatsApp number for this, use a number which isn’t registred with WhatsApp yet.

Update : This solution is not working now. use [matterbridge](https://github.com/42wim/matterbridge) which make use of whatsapp web api (reverse engineered)
full tutorial is [here](https://ibcomputing.com/setting-up-whatsapp-telegram-bridge-using-matterbridge-2020/)

Comment: There is also a fork of wat-bridge by a user called Spechide which provides more features such as media file transfer, sender's name along with the messages, etc. https://github.com/SpEcHiDe/wat-bridge

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** do this since WhatsApp doesn't provide Bot API.

But [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots) is available for free, you can connect it to your own services.